# In Unix, how to display welcome message if user has logged in from a particular IP (or host)?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I want to display one message if user XYZ has logged in from any IP (or host).

Comment: When do you want to display this message? To Whom? To the user when they log in? To an administrator when certain users log in? To the administrator when he asks who's logged in? You could grep the output from the `who` command.

Comment: _has logged in from any IP (or host)_, Do you mean use `ssh`?

Comment: Depending on your reaction on @Loopo, it could be something like `echo "One message"` to the login script of the user `.bashrc` or `.profile`.

Comment: Yes. I want to display Welcome <XYZ> message if user <XYZ> has logged in from any specific ip or host.Or simply i want to display one message if anyone logged in from particular ip or host !

Comment: I want something like ::: If anyone logged in from XXX.XXX.X.X then i want to display Welcome <AAA> and if anyone logged in from YYY.YYY.Y.Y then i want to display Welcome <BBB> ...........................

I hope you got what i want !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you have environment variables such as `SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_CONNECTION` set. If so, you can access these from scripts (perl, bash, etc...) to dynamically generate a welcome message. Below, is a simple perl script to extract the IP address from env var `SSH_CLIENT` and output a welcome message.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $ip = (split / /, $ENV{SSH_CLIENT})[0];
if ($ip eq 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx') {
  print "Hello XXXX\n";
}
else {
  print "Hello from unknown IP\n";
}
```

Then you need to execute this script at login time. You can do this by calling the script from the end of `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Thanks !
It Worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

### Also This can be done using shell script as

```
 REMOTE_IP=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -f1 -d " "`
if [ $REMOTE_IP == 'XXX.XXX.XXX.X' ] ;
      then echo "Hi XXX" ;
else echo "Hi, stranger...";
fi
```

---

And then run this script from /etc/profile